# AVL-дерево и Valgrind

Tags: c, дерево, valgrind

Написал дерево, проверил в Valgrind:

```
==7266== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7266== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7266== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7266== Command: ./lb2
==7266== 
! exit
==7266== 
==7266== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7266==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==7266==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,032 bytes allocated
==7266== 
==7266== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==7266==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7266==    by 0x108F37: AVL_Create (in /home/igor/lb2/lb2)
==7266==    by 0x108BB6: InputFiller (in /home/igor/lb2/lb2)
==7266==    by 0x108A8B: main (in /home/igor/lb2/lb2)
==7266== 
==7266== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7266==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==7266==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7266==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7266==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7266==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7266== 
==7266== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7266== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Т.е. при выходе у меня остается не разименованная память!
Никак не получается найти ошибку:

main.c:

```
/* Системные библиотеки */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Пользовательские библиотеки */
#include "AVL_tree_slimrg.h"
#include "settings_slimrg.h" 

/* Сигнатуры функций */
unsigned short int InputFiller();              // Ввод и исполнение комманд




/* Основной цикл */
int main(){

    // Переменные

    // Считываем и выполняем команды
    InputFiller();

    // Пауза при закрытии
    if (debug_pauseonclose) system("pause"); 

    // Все ОК
    return 0;
}

// Цикл ввода и выполнения
unsigned short int InputFiller(){

    // Переменные
    char tmpchar[StringLengthPS+1];   // Временный контейнер для символа
    char tmpword[StringLengthPS+1];   // Временный контейнер для слова (массива символов)
    unsigned long long int tmpkey;    // Временный контейнер для ключа
    unsigned int i;                   // Тикер (для циклов и т.д.)

    // Создание пустого дерева
    struct avltree* AVLTree1 = AVL_Create();

    // Инициализация
    for (i = 0; i <= 256; i++) {
       tmpchar[i] = tmpword[i] = 0;
    }

    // Пока возможно - считываем первый символ строки
    while (scanf("%s", tmpchar) >= 1){
        // Перевод в нижний регистр
        tmpchar[0]   = tolower(tmpchar[0]);

        // Определение комманды
        switch (tmpchar[0]) {

            // Отладочные комманды
            case '!':
                // Считываем слово
                scanf("%s", tmpword);
                // Перевод в нижний регистр
                for (i = 0; i < StringLengthPS; i++) tmpword[i] = tolower(tmpword[i]);
                // Распознание слова
                if (strcmp(tmpword, "exit") == 0) {
                    return 0;
                } else
                if (strcmp(tmpword, "print") == 0) {
                    AVL_PrintMe(AVLTree1);
                } 
                break;
        }

        // Чистка
        for (i = 0; i <= 256; i++) {
            tmpchar[i] = tmpword[i] = 0;
        }

    }

 // Очистка памяти перед выходом
 AVL_FreeAndNil(AVLTree1);

 // Все ОК
 return 0;
}
```

И сама библиотека AVL_tree_slimrg.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "AVL_tree_slimrg.h"

// Структура строки
struct String{
    char* Text;
    unsigned short int count;
};

// Структура листа
struct avlleaf {
  struct String key;              // Ключ
  unsigned long long int llupar;  // Значение
  long int height;                // Высота
  struct avlleaf* left;          // Левый ребенок
  struct avlleaf* right;         // Правый ребенок
};

// Структура дерева
struct avltree {
    struct avlleaf* root;
};

// Создание дерева
struct avltree* AVL_Create() {
  struct avltree* AVL_Tree = malloc(sizeof(struct avltree));
  AVL_Tree->root = NULL;
  return AVL_Tree;
}

// Уничтожение дерева
void AVL_FreeAndNil(struct avltree* AVL_Tree) {
  // Переменные
  char tmpword[StringLengthPS+1];
  unsigned short int i; // Тикер (для циклов и т.д.)

  // Запускаем балалайку ^_^
  while (AVL_IsEmpty(AVL_Tree) == false) {
    for (i = 0; i <= AVL_Tree->root->key.count; i++) {
        tmpword[i] = AVL_Tree->root->key.Text[i];
    }
    AVL_RemoveLeaf(tmpword, AVL_Tree, false);
  }
}

// Проверка на пустоту
bool AVL_IsEmpty(struct avltree* AVL_Tree) {
  return (AVL_Tree->root == NULL);
}
// Ребалансировка дерева
struct avlleaf* AVL_BalanceMe(struct avlleaf* Leaf) {

  // Переменные
  char balfac; // Коэффицент баласировки (от -2 до +2)


  balfac = AVLLeaf_GetBalance(Leaf);

  // Оцениваем баланс и выправляем его
  if (balfac < -1) {

    // Смотрим, требуется ли большое вращение
    if (AVLLeaf_GetBalance(Leaf->left) > 0) {
      Leaf->left = AVL_rotation_SL(Leaf->left);
    }

    return (AVL_rotation_SR(Leaf));

  } else if (balfac > 1) {

    // Смотрим, требуется ли большое вращение
    if (AVLLeaf_GetBalance(Leaf->right) < 0) {
      Leaf->right = AVL_rotation_SR(Leaf->right);
    }

    return (AVL_rotation_SL(Leaf));

  } else {  // Если нуль

    // Вращение НЕ требуется
    AVLLeaf_CheckHeight(Leaf);

    return Leaf;

  }
}
/ Поиск и удаление
struct avlleaf* AVL_FindAndRemove(char key[StringLengthPS+1], struct avlleaf* Leaf, bool PrintStatus) {

  // Переменные
  struct avlleaf* child;   // Служебная (для случаев с одним ребенком)
  struct String tmpstring; // Строка
  char* tmpkey;            // Временный контейнер для ключа
  unsigned short int i;    // Тикер (для циклов и т.д.)
  int debug;               // Результат сравнения строк [BUG]

  if (Leaf != NULL) debug = strcmp(key, Leaf->key.Text);

  if (Leaf == NULL) {
    // Нет значения для удаления
    if (PrintStatus) printf("NoSuchWord\n");
    return NULL;

  } else if (debug < 0) {

    Leaf->left = AVL_FindAndRemove(key, Leaf->left, PrintStatus);
    return AVL_BalanceMe(Leaf);

  } else if (debug > 0) {

    Leaf->right = AVL_FindAndRemove(key, Leaf->right, PrintStatus);
    return AVL_BalanceMe(Leaf);

  } else { // Найдена позиция
    // Анализ детей и перемещение
    if (Leaf->left != NULL && Leaf->right != NULL) {

      // Очистка и подготовка
      free(Leaf->key.Text);
      Leaf->key.count = 0;

      // Создаем времееный контейнеры
      tmpstring = AVL_GetMinKey(Leaf->right);
      tmpkey = (char*)malloc((StringLengthPS+1)*sizeof(char));


      // Переносим значение
      Leaf->llupar    = AVL_GetMinVal(Leaf->right);
      Leaf->key.count = tmpstring.count;

      // Перевыделение памяти
      Leaf->key.Text = (char*)malloc((Leaf->key.count+1) * sizeof(char));

      // Копирование текста...
      for (i = 0; i <= Leaf->key.count; i++) {
          Leaf->key.Text[i] = tmpkey[i] = tmpstring.Text[i];
      }

      // Удаление дубля
      Leaf->right =   AVL_FindAndRemove(tmpkey, Leaf->right, PrintStatus);

      // Освобождение памяти
      free(tmpkey);

      // Балансировка
      return AVL_BalanceMe(Leaf);

    } else if (Leaf->left != NULL) {

      // Есть только один ребенок (правый)

      if (PrintStatus) printf("OK\n");

      // Наследование
      child = Leaf->left;

      // Освобождение памяти
      Leaf->key.count = 0;
      free(Leaf->key.Text);
      free(Leaf);

      // Возрат ребенка
      return child;

    } else if (Leaf->right != NULL) {

       // Есть только один ребенок (левый)

       if (PrintStatus) printf("OK\n");

      // Наследование
      child = Leaf->right;

      // Освобождение памяти
      Leaf->key.count = 0;
      free(Leaf->key.Text);
      free(Leaf);

      // Возрат ребенка
      return child;

    } else {

      // Нет дитей - просто выкидываем
      if (PrintStatus) printf("OK\n");
      Leaf->key.count = 0;
      free(Leaf->key.Text);
      free(Leaf);
      return NULL;

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Весь код здесь: https://yadi.sk/d/8bk_V6J_qxIeOw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут

```
if (strcmp(tmpword, "exit") == 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

произойдёт выход из функции `InputFiller` без освобождения `AVLTree1`.

Comment: Ой, пропустил
Спасибо, а я грешил на библотеку